# How to make a Bash script to change the format of a date in a CSV file

Tags: bash, scripts, text-processing, csv

I've got a series of CSV files whose second field is dates:

`R.OUSE BOURTON MILL,2000-03-22T14:50:00,Ammoniacal Nitrogen as N,0.03,mg/l`

How can I change the date format into DD/MM/YYYY for all files? The measurement time is not needed.

Thank you so much

Comment: Do you *need* to use `bash`, `cut` or a script as you wrote/tagged?

Comment: I can only use the Bash command line (Mac), a script would be better because I can loop through all the CSV files. Don't necessarily need to use "cut", just thought it could be useful

Comment: I removed the `cut` command tag since it has little to do with your requirements except perhaps cutting the time out of the date field.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

With [miller](https://johnkerl.org/miller/doc/index.html), using its builtin `strptime` and `strftime` functions :

```
$ mlr --fs ',' --ocsvlite --headerless-csv-output put '
    $2 = strftime(strptime($2,"%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S"),"%d/%m/%Y")
  ' file.csv
R.OUSE BOURTON MILL,22/03/2000,Ammoniacal Nitrogen as N,0.03,mg/l
```

Answer (score 2):

Why bash?

From command line:

```
sed -E 's,([0-9]{4})-([0-9]{2})-([0-9]{2}),\3/\2/\1,g' test
```

Result:

```
R.OUSE BOURTON MILL,22/03/2000T14:50:00,Ammoniacal Nitrogen as N,0.03,mg/l
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's a reasonable solution using `bash` and `date`:

```bsh
#!/bin/bash

IFS=,
while read -r line; do
    fields=($line) # Split string into fields
    fields[1]=$(date --date="${fields[1]}" +%d/%m/%Y) # Transform the second date
    echo "${fields[*]}" # Reassemble fields
done <file.csv >>output.csv
```

Comment: It's a nice solution but shouldn't `echo` be going to a new output filename?

Comment: I would put it on the loop instead ```< file.csv >> output.csv```

Comment: @bac0n Sounds good yeah

Answer (score 1):

Match and rearrange time components with [awk](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/String-Functions.html) gensub.

```
$ awk 'BEGIN {FS=OFS=","} {$2=gensub(/(.+)-(.+)-(.+)T.*/,"\\3/\\2/\\1","g",$2)} 1' file.csv # >> output.csv
```

(nawk version):

```
$ awk 'BEGIN {FS=OFS=","} {split(substr($2,0,10),a,"-"); $2=sprintf("%s/%s/%s",a[3],a[2],a[1])} 1' file.csv # >> output.csv
```

if the intention is to only convert the time format, then [epoch](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Time-Functions.html) is probably a better choice.

```
#!/usr/bin/awk -f
#
# example.awk
#
BEGIN {
    FS=OFS=","
} {
    split(substr($2,0,10),a,"-")
    $2=mktime(sprintf("%s %s %s %s %s %s",a[1],a[2],a[3],00,00,00))
} 1
```

```bsh
$ awk -f example.awk file.csv # >> output.csv
```